# A way to find the angle at which to emit a ray so that it hits the target. With the source and target known

Tags: unity-game-engine, reflection, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, raycasting

I wanted to make an AI that makes the decision to shoot a reflecting laser towards the target accurately from it's position, reflecting from a stable, non moving smooth surface like a mirror.

One option is to rotate the ray until it finds the position to hit the mirror so that the laser hits the target after reflection. But I would like to consider more options apart from the apparent brute force method.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. So you want us to write the code?

Comment: No, just tell me a method or a formula to perform the calculation apart from randomly rotating the raycast direction until it hits the target, or may never hit the target. 

If you can write the code though than you are more than welcome to. @Programmer

Comment: I agree! Brute Force is a good solution here, However, considering performance I would suggest that raycasting should be gapped evenly based on width/radius of the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

1. Find the Perpendicular intersection(**C**) from Player(**P**) to the reflection plane.
2. Then find the Transpose point (**T**) of **P**. Meaning, C will be the center point of T and P.
3. Raycast from AI(**A**) to **T**. Let the hit point be **X** on the reflection plane.
   or
   You can just ignore 3rd point and shoot towards Vector **(T-A)**

Then **X** will be the point where the AI should hit.
You can try out this link for finding the perpendicular intersection:
http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Plan3D/PlaneLineIntersection_.htm

Comment: Step 3 isn't necessary, 1+2 will suffice since the angle to **T** is the same as the angle to **X**.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the vector spanning between source's actual position and the target's apparent position in the mirror.

1. The apparent position of the target in the mirror is just its actual position reflected across the plane of the mirror
2. The vector between two points **A** and **B** is **B-A**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was exactly what I was looking for :)